# jQuery .is() not working

Tags: jquery

Quick Question:

HTML:

```
<div class='aaa'>Text</div>
<div class='aaa'>Text</div>
<div class='aaa'>Text</div>
<div class='aaa'>Text</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.aaa').on('click', function(){
    var check = $(this).is('.aaa:last');
    alert(check);
});
```

How come it always alerts "false"? I'm expecting it to alert "true" when I click the last div?

Where am I doing wrong?

**Edit --**

I know why finally. My jQuery version is 1.9.1. It works fine when jQuery is 2.x –

Comment: Can't duplicate: http://jsfiddle.net/f3cvaLpw/

Answer (score 2):

It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/jef0nhmq/

Your code is fine.

```
$('.aaa').on('click', function(){
   var check = $(this).is('.aaa:last');
   alert(check);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works with `:last-child`